# Why Division yields results with more decimal values in javascript

Tags: javascript

When I do the below operation, I am getting the result as below.

Actual : 5.9 / 100 = 0.059000000000000004

Expected : 5.9 / 100 = 0.059

Anyone has idea?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Numbers):

> ## Numbers
>
> Numbers in JavaScript are "double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754
> values", according to the spec. This has some interesting
> consequences. There's no such thing as an integer in JavaScript, so
> you have to be a little careful with your arithmetic if you're used to
> math in C or Java.
>
> Also, watch out for stuff like:
>
> ```
> 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.30000000000000004;
> ```
>
> In practice, integer values are treated as 32-bit ints, and some
> implementations even store it that way until they are asked to perform
> an instruction that's valid on a Number but not on a 32-bit integer.
> This can be important for bit-wise operations.
>
> The standard arithmetic operators are supported, including addition,
> subtraction, modulus (or remainder) arithmetic, and so forth. There's
> also a built-in object that we did not mention earlier called Math
> that provides advanced mathematical functions and constants: